# connection string error to sql server 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

I try to connect my c# application to sql server 2012 
my connection string is

```
connectionString="Server=.\MSSQLSERVER; Database=|AppData|\TechnicalOfficeManagerDB.mdf; Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

the application raise exception said 
the value's length for key exceeds it's limit of '128' and don't connect to `sql server`

I don't understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look this website : http://www.connectionstrings.com/

There is an example here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

> Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
>   Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Try removing "\" after AppData

```
connectionString="Server=.\MSSQLSERVER; Database=|AppData|TechnicalOfficeManagerDB.mdf; Trusted_Connection=True;"
```